# Trouble connecting RxPagingSource to a Volley call using Java

Tags: android, android-volley, android-paging

I am trying to Load and display paged data from Volley and having a little trouble connecting the data source to my backend service. Most examples are in Kotlin but I have been following [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data#java) and [a LoopWiki example](https://www.loopwiki.com/library/paging-3-android-example-in-java-building-movies-application/). Since the latter is using Retrofit and I am using Volley I have been trying to bounce between the two to come up with something.

This piece of code from the Android documentation shows the call but uses a hypothetical backend. I would like to plug my Volley call into this:

```
  @NotNull
  @Override
  public Single<LoadResult<Integer, User>> loadSingle(
    @NotNull LoadParams<Integer> params) {
    // Start refresh at page 1 if undefined.
    Integer nextPageNumber = params.getKey();
    if (nextPageNumber == null) {
      nextPageNumber = 1;
    }

    return mBackend.searchUsers(mQuery, nextPageNumber)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .map(this::toLoadResult)
      .onErrorReturn(LoadResult.Error::new);
  }
```

When I have been using volley I have been passing in a listener and calling it

```
public void getData(Application application, ResultsListener listener) {
    ...

    if (listener!=null)
        listener.onReturn(arrayList);

}

public interface ResultsListener {
    void onReturn(List<MyObject> objectList);
}
```

But this approach doesn't seem like a good fit here. I am somewhat new and have gotten in the habit of using listeners but I expect there is a better approach.

What do I need to do to get .subscribeOn, .map, and .OnErrorReturn on a search method in a class?

I have the paging functioning in my API.